# Is it possible to have 2 functions in 1 cell with a seperator?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble figuring out how to use fit 2 =SUM formulas into 1 cell with a seperator('/' or '|')

Formula 1: =SUM(Sheet2!E28) - 1
Formula 2: =SUM(Sheet3!C19) - 2

The result would be something like 1/2 or 1|2, is this possible?

Comment: Are you summing a single cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. One of simple way is to use concatenation operator `&`. Try-

```
=SUM(Sheet2!E28)-1 & "|" & SUM(Sheet3!C19)-2
```

Another way is to use `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SUM(Sheet2!E28)-1,SUM(Sheet3!C19)-2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was doing the first one but was leaving the 2nd '=' on the formula. much appreciated!